# Common python modules required by multiple repositories: should I package as submodules or just list as dependency?

Tags: python, git, github

I have a module common_analysis_tools.py that I use in multiple Python projects.  These projects are set up as repositories on GitHub so that I can share them with collaborators (I work in a research science environment, not a development environment).  When it comes to packaging my code should the common_analysis_tools be included in each repository (e.g. as a submodule or some other way), or should I just have a separate repository for the common_analysis_tools and list this package as a dependency of my other projects?

(I'm sorry if this is answered elsewhere - I have searched old posts, but haven't found an answer - if this isn't the case I'm happy for someone to point me in the right direction!  Thanks!)

Comment: Do you want people to be able to freeze on specific versions? If so, it's probably simpler to use `pip` instead of `git` to manage that—make it a separate project and put it on an internal package index that you can push releases to. But if not, submodules are probably a good idea.

Comment: For now, I'm not supporting this code in any way and making it available as-is.  Sounds like either way the common_analysis_tools should be its own package, and I can include it as a submodule for now, possibly switching to pip for superior management down the road.

Comment: If this is just a one-time dump, it really doesn't matter _how_ you do it. You can make it a dependency they have to pull manually into their own code, or a git submodule, or a Python package, and the only difference is the one line you'll write in a README or internal wiki or whatever on how to set up for development.

Comment: It's not a one-time dump - I'm continuing to develop the code, but currently the sole developer and only a smaller number of people are using it, who I directly communicate with when there are any updates.  Thanks btw!

Comment: In that case, whether you do submodule or manual pulls probably comes down to whether you want them to have the newest version by default, or the last version they asked for by default.